# Determine whether $f_n(x)= n\int_0^{1/n} f(x-u) du$ uniformly converges to $f$ or not.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-convergence

Let $f$ be continuous on $\mathbb R.$

Define $\{f_n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \}_{n=1}^\infty \ $ by $f_n(x)= n \displaystyle\int_0^{1/n} f(x-u) \ du$.

Then, for all $x\in \mathbb R,$ $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n (x)=f(x)$ holds. (I already proved.)

---

Then, determine whether  $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly or not.

I think $f_n$ doesn't uniformly converge to $f$.

A counter example is $f(x)=x^2.$(This is continuous on $\mathbb R.$)

Let $f(x)=x^2$, and suppose $f_n(x)=n \displaystyle\int_0^{1/n} f(x-u) du$ converges to $f$ uniformly .

Then, there is $N \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $$n \geqq N \Rightarrow |f_n (x)-f(x)|<\frac{2}{3} \mathrm{\ for \ all \ } x \in \mathbb R.$$

Thus, $|f_N(N)-f(N)|<\dfrac{2}{3}$ must hold.

However,
\begin{align}
|f_N(N)-f(N)|
&=N \left|\int_0^{1/N} f(N-u)-f(N) du \right| \\
&=N \left|\int_0^{1/N} (N-u)^2-N^2 du \right| \\
&=N \left|\int_0^{1/N} -2Nu+u^2 du \right| \\
&=1-\frac{1}{3N^2}\\
&\geqq 1-\frac{1}{3}\\
&=\frac{2}{3}.
\end{align}
This is contradiction.

Therefore, I think $f(x)=x^2$ is a counter example.

Is my idea correct ?

Comment: +1Looks correct to me!